# ajax application that will display a content of glossary json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am trying to accomplish the goal of  build an  ajax application that will display a content  of  glossary json file .

First , we have the glossary .json codes .

```
  {
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "Acronym": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is my tried codes of the Ajax for glossary.Json file :

```
       <html>
      <head><title>Glossary</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
     var httpRequest;
     function makeRequest() {

var url="glossary.JSON"; 
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange",getXMLContents,false); 
//httpRequest.onreadystatechange (getXMLContents, false);
httpRequest.open("GET",url ,true);
httpRequest.send();
   }

    function getXMLContents() {

var textObj;

if ((httpRequest.readyState == 4) && (httpRequest.status == 200))
     {
        textObj=document.getElementById("data");
            var glossaryObject = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText); ;
        var details="";
        for(var property in glossaryObject)
        {
            if (property == "GlossEntry")
            { 
                details += "GlossEntry ID= " +
                glossaryObject[property].ID ;
                details += " GlossEntry SortAs=" + glossaryObject  [property].SortAs ;
     details += "GlossEntry GlossTerm= " +
                glossaryObject[property].GlossTerm ;


    details += "GlossEntry Acronym= " +
                glossaryObject[property].Acronym ;


        details += "GlossEntry Abbrev= " +
                glossaryObject[property].Abbrev ;




details += "GlossDef =" +glossaryObject  [property].GlossDef.para;
            }
            else{
                details += property + " = " + glossaryObject[property] ;
                    }
        }//for
            textObj.innerHTML=details; // Put data in document
    } //status



        }

      </script>
       </head>
       <body>
       <input type="button" value="Details" 
onclick = "makeRequest()" >
Get glossary details

      <div id="data">
       </div>
       </body>
        </html>
```

I expected the result will be a page that have bottom and when the bottom clicked the   contents of the glossary will display in one line .My problem is when I click the bottom noting is come although I wrote all the objects Why ?

Comment: Its time to open the firebug console and check for any errors.!

Comment: i tried to download it but i coudnt .Can u give me the right  link ?